# Base64 encoded string saves incorrectly to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string

I'm struggling several hours on this issue.

I have a long string. The value is base64_encoded json data.
When I'm doing var_dump or saving the string to MySQL it gets cut off. But it saves correctly to file.

This is the output saved to file. (correct)
http://pastebin.com/Brr9a271

This is the data saved to MySQL blob field. (cutted). Same appears when I do var_dump
http://pastebin.com/u1xNAnUb

What am I missing? Can this be a PHP bug?

Comment: Did you check the blob field was large enough ? And why encode in base64 if you store the data in a binary field ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has about 86KiB, but a BLOB column with a maximum length of 65,535.
Use **MEDIUMBLOB**.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) :

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYBLOB |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      BLOB |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMBLOB |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGBLOB | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using char (or var char) juding by the length (size: 64.00 KB )

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

try using text or blob

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: No. TEXT and BLOB both have limit of 65535.

Answer (score 0):

For storing a **base64 encoded data** change your datatype in the **MYSQL** table to **LONGTEXT**.

Have a look !!!

```
TINYTEXT - 255 bytes
TEXT - 65535 bytes
MEDIUMTEXT - 16,777,215 bytes (2^24 - 1)
LONGTEXT - 4G bytes (2^32 – 1)

TINYBLOB - 255 bytes
BLOB - 65535 bytes
MEDIUMBLOB - 16,777,215 bytes (2^24 - 1)
LONGBLOB - 4G bytes (2^32 – 1)
```